# Does resolving a merge conflict modify both the source and destination file?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I had an open PR from `source branch` —> `destination branch`, and there was a conflict in one of the files. So I checked out `source branch`, ran `git merge destination branch`, and then resolved the conflicts in the conflicted file, ran `git commit` and `git push`. When I then looked at my open PR, I was expecting to see the conflicted file still in the diff between the two branches with the new changes, but the file disappeared entirely, implying there is no difference in this file between the `source branch` and `destination branch`. Am I understanding correctly that resolving conflicts in a git merge applies the changes to both the source file and destination file, or did something else happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The merge only changes the branch on which you push the merge commit. In your case, you merged into `source` and pushed, which means that `source` now contains the changes from `destination` plus whatever you did to resolve the conflict.

If you did not push any changes to `destination`, the contents of that branch have not changed. They will only change if you push the merge commit to that branch too.

If the PR now tells you that there are no changes in that file introduced by your PR, I suspect that means you ended up making it identical between modified `source` and the original `destination`. You can confirm that by doing `git diff source destination` on an updated sandbox on your computer.